# Remind event based on the date android

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android , and I am designing an app that reminds event , I am not aware of how to get started to achieve this .

I stored the Date Month Year of the event in the database , the thing I need is

Run a background service that looks for the event to occur

push notification based on time set by the user , also days set that is 1 days before , 15 days before

Please help me how to achieve this

Comment: see here clear description hope this will help you http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: My app is purely an offline app.. Can u suggest me any simple tutorial  so that I am get the basic concept

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

You can register a pending intent to be triggered at any time, or periodically. You can then make the pending intent trigger a broadcast or a service or just a notification, if I remember correctly. Just check [this](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.it/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html) or google for Notification / AlarmManager.
This way is more power efficient than just run a background service that checks periodically if it needs to notify the user.